# Debiasing after LASSO in R

Tags: r, python, lasso, bias, bias-correction

I'm doing machine learning analysis (Lasso) in R.

Lasso introduces bias, and I heard I can recover less biased (or unbiased) coefficient estimates by debiasing methods. Is there any R package that can do this? I'm also happy to use Python.

Answer (score 2):

3 ways I can suggest to get less biased estimates while still performing feature selection (using LASSO/L1 like regularisation):

1. Perform an ordinary least squares fit on the features that are selected by a LASSO model.
2. The [relaxnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaxnet/index.html) package for R. This fits a '[relaxed LASSO](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947306004956)' model, which gives you another hyperparameter that you can use to 'control' the bias.
3. Use [SCAD](http://orfe.princeton.edu/~jqfan/papers/01/penlike.pdf) or the [MC+](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4734) estimators available in the [ncvreg](https://cran.r-project.org/package=ncvreg) package which can use some slightly more advanced regularisation functions which result in less biased estimates.